# Can i write preprocessor directives anywhere in my c program?

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

Is it mandatory to write #include at the top of the program and outside the main function?

I tried using #define preprocessor inside the main function and it worked fine with only one exception..that being  the constant which i defined using the define directive can be used only after the line #define  
For instance say `printf("%d",PI); #define PI 3.14`will give error "Undefined symbol PI". But in the following code i did not encounter any error

```
#define PI 3.14 
printf("%d",PI);
```

Is this because C is a procedural language and procedural languages implements top down approach?

Also i would like to know that can we  use  only #define inside the main function or other preprocessor directives too?  If we can use then which ones? 
Or is it the other way around, instead of #include we can use all the preprocessor directives in the main function?

Comment: "the following code i did not encounter any error" --> Code is attempting to print a `double` with `"%d"` --> UB.  Enable all compiles warnings.

Comment: Note that the C standard (and I believe the POSIX standard) require that headers they define must be included at file scope and not within the scope of an external declaration (function, or in the middle of a variable declaration).   You may use `#include` with your own headers wherever you like; the onus is on you to make it work correctly. If your header includes a system header, you'll have to obey the file scope rules after all.  Note that although the includes are normally at the top of the file, that isn't a requirement.

Comment: If you fix the code as ``#define PI 3.14 
printf("%f",PI);`` , the question remains why does the order matter. Then it is a procedural issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only place you can't put a preprocessor directive is in a macro expansion. The sole exception is `#pragma`, which can also be written `_Pragma()`.

This has nothing to do with "procedural", but due to the fact that C is defined in terms of 8 translation phases, each of which is "as-if" fully-completed before the next phase. For more details, see the C11 standard, section 5.1.1.2.

---

One example of when it is *useful* to use preprocessor directives after the start of a file is for the ["X Macro" technique](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Macro) (which many people only know as "those `.def` files").

Comment: I would add a note that it's usually sufficient to look at the freely available C standard drafts, otherwise newbies willl hit a paywall and never read the specs anyways

Answer (score 1):

Preprocessor directives work pretty much anywhere. Of course, you can make your code confusing pretty easily if you abuse this.

Comment: Unfortunately #include is not working everywhere..Why so? I took a simple example.. Say int main(void) { #include<math.h> } and i got 6 errors in turbo c compiler mostly of undefined symbols

Comment: `#include` does indeed work everywhere... but what it does is copy-and-paste the contents of the included file into the spot where you put the `#include` directive. So if you stick it inside `main`, it will dutifully put the contents of `math.h` inside your `main` function, which probably won't compile. But if you had a file containing code that would compile inside a `main` function and you `#include`d that, it would work fine (not that I'd recommend actually doing that).

Comment: @CharlesSrstka, #include does work in many places; it is header which was written to be included into global scope. There is software with `#define some_macro some value` and #include "special.c"; sometimes arrays are filled with included files.

Answer (score 1):

The pre-processor does its work before the compiler performs the source code translation into object code. Pre-processing is mostly a string replacement task, so it can be placed just about anywhere in your code. Of course, if the resulting expansion is syntactically incorrect, the expanded source code will fail to compile.

A commonly tolerated practice is to embed conditional compilation directives inside a function to allow the function to use platform specific APIs.

```
void some_wrapper_function () {
#if defined(UNIX)
    some_unix_specific_function();
#elif defined(WIN32)
    some_win32_specific_function();
#else
    #error "Compiled on an unsupported platform"
#endif
}
```

By their nature, the directives themselves normally have to be defined at the beginning of the line, and not somewhere in the middle of source line. But, defined macros can of course appear anywhere in the source, and will be replaced according to the substitution rules defined by your directives.

Comment: `_Pragma` is a pre-processor operator, not a directive, and acts like `#pragma` except the operator version can be used anywhere you might use a macro.

Answer (score 1):

The trick here is to realize that # directives have traditionally been interpreted by a pre-processor, that runs before any compilation. The pre-processor would produce a new source file, which was then compiled. I don't think any modern compiler works that way by default, but the same principles apply.

So when you say

```
#include "foo.h"
```

you're saying "insert the entire contents of foo.h into my source code starting at this line."

You can use this directive pretty much anywhere in a source file, but it's rarely useful (and not often readable) to use it anywhere other than at the start of the source.